# Find $\sin(1/10)$ to within error of $10^{-7}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, estimation

The maclaurin series of $\sin(x)$ is $x- x^3/3! + x^5/5! - \cdots + (-1)^n  x^{2n+1}/(2n+1)!$.

My teacher wants me to use [Taylor's inequality theorem on page 607](http://books.google.com/books?id=uYxE7bzhh08C&pg=PA608&lpg=PA608&dq=taylor%27s+inequality+formula+stewart&source=bl&ots=PYmGHkGEfE&sig=rJt5OorULP5t375sjkXF9vXWx-A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c_gYUumFG8qoigLxwoHYDg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=taylor%27s%20inequality%20formula%20stewart&f=false) to solve this problem.

I know that the alternating series test can apply, but I'm required to use Taylor's theorem for this problem.  I think that $M$ is equal to $1$, $a$ is equal to $0$, and so I have $10^{-7}\le (1/10)^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ but I don't know how to solve for n and I'm not sure if that setup is correct.

Comment: You don't need to solve for $n$. Just keep putting in values of $n$ until you find one that works. It won't be that hard.

Comment: Please don't make us dig around through a fuzzy image of a page in a book. Please copy down the theorem you want us to see in your question. This particular theorem is standard, but there are several slightly different ones with similar names dealing with similar things, so it will be helpful to have it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Note the very useful fact that the Taylor polynomial of $\sin x$ up to and including the term in $x^{2n+1}$ is exactly the same as the Taylor polynomial up to and including the term in $x^{2n+2}$.

The $(2n+2)$-th derivative of $\sin t$ is one of $\cos t$ or $-\cos t$, so it has absolute value $\le 1$.  We can therefore take $M=1$.

The absolute value of the error when we cut off at the term in $x^{2n+1}$ is therefore less than
$$\frac{1}{(2n+3)!} |x|^{2n+3}.$$

With $x=\frac{1}{10}$, the error quickly gets below $10^{-7}$. Already it is a bit below at $n=1$.

So the approximation $\sin x\approx x-\frac{x^3}{3!}$ is good enough when $x=\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: How did you get (2n+3) instead of (n+1) in your denominator and exponential?  I'm confused because that's what my teacher did too, but (n+1) is in the formula for the theorem.

Comment: Well, if you prefer you can use $n$, but *immediately* call it $2k+1$, as a reminder that it is odd. Or stick with $n$. It is basically an "aesthetic" decision, it will not change the answer. You will then come to the conclusion that you should go to $n=3$, that is, to $x-\frac{x^3}{3!}$. That will keep you closer to the formula in the book.

Comment: I found that n=3 is the answer too, but I plugged it into the series for the expansion of sin(x) which got me to x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!.  I'm guessing that's wrong then.

Comment: Not wrong exactly, you will get greater accuracy than required, and will have expended more computing effort. You have not found the smallest $n$. The error when you cut off just after the $x^3$ term is, by my calculation above, less than $\frac{10^{-5}}{5!}$. Since $5!=120$, the error is $\lt 10^{-7}$.  If you don't take advantage of the fact that the polynomial to $x^3$ is the same as the polynomial to $x^4$, you can easily end up with an $n$ that is bigger than necessary.